# How do I handle storage in a Java console app that cannot use DB?

Tags: java

I am given an assignment where we are not allowed to use a DB or libraries but only textfile for data storage.

But it has rather complex requirements, for e.g. many validations, because of that, we need to "access the db" (i.e. read the textfile) many times.

My question is: should I create a class like this:

```
class SomeRepository{
   static ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList();

   public SomeRepository(){
       //instantiate this class on program load
       //In constructor, we read the text file, instantiate and store everything inside the arraylist.
   }

   //public getOneUser(){ // for get methods, we don't read from text file at all }

   /public save() { //text file saving code overhere }
}
```

Is this a good approach to solve the above problem? Currently, what we are doing is reading and writing to the text file every time we want to retrieve some data or write something new.

Wouldn't this be too expensive in terms of heap space memory? Or should I just read/write to the text file for every method?

Comment: you can solve this issue just by using files to store your data and read it back from files, try this link to know more about working with files: https://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/how-to-read-and-write-text-file-in-java

Comment: But that means every time I read the file, I have to deserialize the text into Java objects, correct? Even if I'm just trying to find one object, I should also just store in text file and retrieve from text file?

Comment: you just need to read file every time when you run your application at start.

Comment: "but only textfile for data storage.". Are you allowed to use serialization?

Comment: yes, have to deserialize to java objects and I guess serialize when we want to write back to text file

Comment: In which case, just make two general methods: (1) serialize and save objects (2) read file and deserialize object. I can give you a code snippet to use if you want

Comment: Oh yes, thank you please! I knew something was wrong when we were writing and saving to the file in every method

Comment: Just to clarify. What type of system environment are we talking here? Windows, linux, android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public class IOManager {

    public static void writeObjToTxtFile(String fileName, Object object) {
        File file = new File(fileName + ".txt");//File will be created in the root directory where the program runs.
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);) {
            oos.writeObject(object);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Object readObjFromTxtFile(String fileName) {
        Object obj = null;
        File file = new File(fileName + ".txt");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            obj = ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }

}
```

Add this class to your project. Since it's general for all Objects, you can pass and receive Objects like these as well: `ArrayList<Users>`. Play around and Tinker with it to fit whatever your specific purpose is. Hint: You can write other custom methods that calls these methods. eg:

```java
    public static void writeUsersToFile(ArrayList<Users> usersArrayList){
        writeObjToTxtFile("users",usersArrayList);
    }
```

Ps. Make sure your Objects implement Serializable. Eg:

```java
public class Users implements Serializable {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the contents of your file to a dynamic list such as an arraylist at the start of your program. Make the required queries/changes to your arraylist and then write that arraylist to your file when the program is set to close. This will save significant time over repeated file reads/writes.

This isn't without it's drawbacks, though. You don't want to hogg up memory in case of very large files - but considering this is an assignment, that may not be the case. Additionally, should your program terminate prior to the write at the end, all changes made to your database during the current execution will be lost.